# Issue with Next.js Routing and Cookie Storage for Dynamic Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, routes

I am working on a Next.js application with the following folder structure:

[image]

In the header of my application, I have a list of classes, and when I click on a class, it routes to the page `[class_slug]` where I fetch data from an API using the last slug from the URL. To maintain context, I store the `class_id` in cookies.

I display different boards on the `[class_slug]` page that the user can click on. Upon clicking a specific board, the application redirects to the `[id]` page while storing both the `class_id` and `board_id` in cookies. The `[id]` page fetches data from the API using these parameters from the cookies.

This workflow has been functioning correctly. However, after creating a sitemap, I noticed that the generated URLs (e.g., http://localhost:3000/education/result/bise-lahore-9th-class-result) don't seem to store the IDs in cookies. As a result, when I try to directly access the page in the private mood using these URLs, the IDs are null, rendering the page inaccessible.

How can I ensure that the IDs are correctly stored in cookies when accessing pages directly via URLs generated by the sitemap? Is there a better approach to maintain context and handle routing while avoiding this issue?

Any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. I really appreciate any help you can provide.